# Detect when user scrolled down and reached center of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Currently I have the following code which detects when a user has started scrolling and if they've reached the center of the page.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop()  > $(window).height() / 2) {
            //Load more posts
        }
});
```

However the problem I have is that whenever a user starts scrolling, the above script fires. So if a user scrolls up to view previous posts, this loads more posts. If a user is in the center and scrolls just a tiny bit, the script loads more posts.

My question is, is there a way to determine when a user has started to scroll down AND has reached the center of the newly resized page, because of more appended posts.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you load more posts once `$(window).scrollTop()` is less than half the window height?

Comment: Also, have you tried using `$(document).height()/2` instead of window?

Comment: What is the main difference between using $(document) and $(window)?

Comment: @user2028856 On this page, with `console` open / visible on `window` `$(window).height() // 269`, `$(document).height() // 2284`

Comment: Exactly what @guest271314 is pointing out - `$(document)` is the entire html document rendered - even what is not visible. `$(window)` is the visible document. Because you will be loading posts that will not be visible until you scroll to see them, I think `$(document)` is what you are looking for. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user2028856 Is "center of the page" requirement "center" of entire `document`, or center of `window` (view-able region of page) ?

Comment: @ThoughtfulThighentist yea I get it now. I'm going to try with $(document).height() instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on("scroll.y", function(e) {
  if ($("body").scrollTop() >= ( ($(e.target).height() / 2) -250) ) {
       console.log("approximate center"); $(e.target).off("scroll.y")
  };
  return false
})
```