# Making an element fill the entire height of browser viewport using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/F5dxk/)**
**[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/F5dxk/show/light/)**

The basic form of HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="home">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <!-- blah, blah, blah! -->

        </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

W.r.t the HTML, I am trying to make the element `#main` fill the entire height of the browser viewport using JavaScript/jQuery like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // get height of browser viewport
    var window_h = $(window).height();

    // get height of the jumbotron, i.e. element #main
    var jumbotron_h = $('.home #main').outerHeight(true);

    // calculate necessary padding (top/bottom) to apply on #main so that the
    // element's height is equal to that of the browser's viewport,
    // and its contents are centered vertically
    if (window_h > (jumbotron_h + 60)) {
        var jumbotron_padding = (window_h - jumbotron_h)/2
    } else {
        var jumbotron_padding = 30
    }

    // apply calculated padding on the element dynamically
    $('.home #main').attr('style', 'padding-top:'+jumbotron_padding+'px;padding-bottom:'+jumbotron_padding+'px;');

});
```

As clearly explained in the comments in the code above, the code automatically calculates the necessary padding to be applied on `#main` so that its height is equal to that of the browser's viewport.

It works well, except, the calculated padding (and therefore the resultant height) is wrong in one case that I was able to identify.

Easily reproducible *at least* on **Windows 7, Google Chrome browser** (latest) when you resize the browser window to 567x724 px, which implies 551x611 px viewport size, (you can use an extension like [Window Resizer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh)), you'll notice that the element's calculated padding results in its height being larger than that of the browser's viewport.

Why is this happening? I wasn't able to reproduce the same at any other resolution. What could I possibly be missing here?

Comment: why using jQuery when you can do it with pure css ?

Comment: So looking at your code, it appears that you're primarily trying to keep the #main element centered vertically. There are easier ways to do this with CSS. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @KarimAG I tried. (1) absolute positioning is causing `#main` element to collapse, thereby breaking format of its contents. (2) even after absolute positioning `#main`, vertically centering it is a pain (what % from top and bottom) and needs a hack or two (3) there isn't a set height on `#main` + the web page is designed responsively, which only makes things much more harder

Comment: @its_me Could add more elements to http://jsfiddle.net/F5dxk/ ? Not appear to have a `resize` `event` attached ? Not able to reproduce issue, without `resize` or `scroll` .  Thanks

Comment: This page has several suggestions that all use CSS and several of them are responsive. I've used a couple in the past on my own (nice to know I wasn't the only one who came up with those solutions). http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Comment: @its_me See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746887/detect-when-user-scrolled-down-and-reached-center-of-page/22752111#22752111

Comment: @its_me Will additional content be added to the page, or is the entire content (`html`) in post above ? Thanks

Comment: @its_me Not certain, is requirement to maintain `#main` at "center" of page ? thanks

Comment: @guest271314 No, additional content will not be added to the page. The JS Fiddle includes the entire content. And yes, it's a requirement to maintain `#main` at the center of the page -- which your answer doesn't do. *(Internet connectivity issues yesterday; so I couldn't reply earlier.)*

Comment: @Thomas Of all the solutions in the link you posted, only one (using table-cell) seems to do what I am after. I'll give it a shot. Thanks! *(Internet connectivity issues yesterday; so I couldn't reply earlier.)*

Comment: @its_me Just to make you aware, I've had a lot of issues trying to build pages that center vertically. If the viewport is smaller than your content, your content will get cut off. You'll get a scrollbar for the content that gets cut off at the bottom, but the content that gets cut off at the top is lost forever. I've found it better to just space the content with margins/padding so it looks close enough to center on most browsers. Here's a link to some stats about browser window size: http://dunnbypaul.net/sizeview/

Comment: @Thomas I share your concerns, which is exactly why the *if browser's viewport height is less than that of the element* part, i.e. `if (window_h <= (jumbotron_h + 60)) {` exists in my code. It takes care of the issue of content getting cut off, and adds extra padding of 60px in the concerned cases.

Comment: @its_me Please describe `vertical` and `horizontal` positions of `#main` which appears "off-center" at jsfiddle pages ? Browser, screen resolutions ? Thanks

Comment: @guest271314 `#main` only needs to be centered vertically; I never said horizontally.

Comment: @its_me If interpret requirement accurately, ok if `#main` positioned at `left` "side" of `viewport` ?

Answer (score 1):

First off, Jquery's `.outerheight()` function *includes* padding, which means that when you measure the height of your `#Main` element after this function runs the first time, it will equal the `window.height`. In other words - it will look awful when you resize your browser. You can see this in action on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaycenornin/F5dxk/3/show/light/) when you resize the browser window the old-fashioned way. You can use margins instead, but then you'll have to adjust your CSS quite a bit. Even then, resizing the window still looks awful and buggy and has inconsistent results across browsers. You can see that on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaycenornin/F5dxk/2/show/light/).

The specific bug you're referring to is probably due to inconsistent math when you resize your window - a combination of your use of padding (which is included in `.outerheight()` as mentioned above) and the viewport size not being easily divisible by 2 (it's impossible to have half a pixel and different browsers will render that half a pixel differently).

I should also point out this line of code:

```
if (window_h > (jumbotron_h + 60)) {
    var jumbotron_padding = (window_h - jumbotron_h)/2
} else {
    var jumbotron_padding = 30
}
```

This forces your page to always be `#main.height() + 60`, which can be bigger than your viewable window, depending upon your window size. `#main.height()` comes out to around 200.5px (there we are with another half pixel).

Assuming that your goal is to vertically center the `#Main` element, your best bet is to use one of the many straight CSS methods available. [The table method](http://vanseodesign.com/blog/demo/vertical-centering/table-cell.php) seems most applicable here because it is completely dynamic (and thus can be responsive) - simply create a single cell CSS table, use CSS valign, and build your entire page inside that cell. For older versions of IE you'll need to use a tiny hack (`display:Inline-block;`) to make it work.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {display: table;}

#child {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

IE fix:

```
#child {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I've identified two possible solutions based on your answer: <http://stackoverflow.com/a/22804845/1071413>. Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

*Based on @Thomas's answer, I've identified two possible solutions. I am going with the **#2** solution considering better browser support for it.*

---

**1.** Using the unit `vh` (viewport height). [Browser support](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units): IE9 and above.

**CSS:**

```
.home #primary { /* Parent */
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.home #main { /* Child */
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100vh; /* 100% viewport height */
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

---

**2.** Dynamically setting height of parent (`.home #primary`) equal to that of browser's viewport.

**JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var window_h = $(window).height();
    var jumbotron_h = $('.home #main').height();

    if (window_h <= (jumbotron_h + 60)) {
        var window_h = jumbotron_h + 60
    }

    $('.home #primary').attr('style', 'height:'+window_h+'px;');

});
```

**CSS:**

```
.home #primary { /* Parent */
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.home #main { /* Child */
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%; /* 100% height of parent */
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       body {
        height:100vh;
       }

       .element-to-be-centered { 
        font-size:1em; 
        text-align:center; 
        top: 49%;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-49%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-49%);
        transform: translateY(-49%);
       }
```

I have been doing quite a bit of experimenting lately with centering content. This technique will work without having to set a height on any element.

This will work in ie9 and up.

Answer (score -1):

In your CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

div, #main {
    height: 100%;
}
```