# Using jQuery to set height of an element dynamically; how to reset height on .resize() event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider this example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    function elementHeight() {

        // Get height of the browser viewport
        var windowH = $(window).height();

        // Set element's height (i.e. #elementID) equal to
        // that of the browser's viewport
        $('#elementID').height(windowH+'px');
    }

    elementHeight();

    // Make sure the height is recalculated and set on the
    // element when the browser is resized
    $(window).resize(function() {
        elementHeight();
    });

});
```

The code above sets the height of element `#elementID` so that it's equal to the height of the browser's viewport.

But the browser's viewport size changes when it's resized and ideally, so should the element's height. So, I want the code to also change the height of `#elementID` so that it's always equal to the browser's viewport, i.e. even when the browser is resized by the user.

I tried using the `.resize()` event, as you can see in the code above, but I seem to be doing it wrong.

Because instead of replacing the height of the element (initially calculated when the code is run for the first time), the height keeps adding up (x + y + z + ...) everytime the browser is resized, making the element's height bigger and bigger.

What am I doing wrong? And how should it be done?

---

**NOTE:** I also tried these instead of `$('#elementID').height(windowH+'px');`

```
$('#elementID').css('height',windowH+'px');

$('#elementID').attr('style', 'height:'+windowH+'px;');
```

They didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#elementID').height(windowH);
```

If you want to add the px I think this is how it should be done:

```
$('#elementID').css('height',windowH + 'px');
```

I would be anyways recommend using the .css as it is faster :)

Comment: I tried that. Didn't make any difference. Added a note in my question to reflect the same.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you could do something like

```
function checkResizeAndReady() {
   var windowHeight = $(window).height();
   $('#height').css('height', windowHeight + "px");
}

$(window).on("resize", checkResizeAndReady);
$(document).on("ready", checkResizeAndReady);
```

http://codepen.io/RobErskine/pen/efEGc/

Or conversely, you could use CSS:

```
body,html{
   display:block;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   margin:0;
}

#filler{
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
 }
```

http://codepen.io/RobErskine/pen/aezkG/

Comment: I'll try your jQuery solution. Your CSS solution doesn't cut it for me because it doesn't allow me to vertically center the elements contents. Here's more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22804845/1071413

Comment: Just tried the jQuery solution. The problem persists.

Comment: Well, what didn't work about it? There's a working codepen included. You can also vertically center anything in CSS using this technique - http://codepen.io/RobErskine/pen/KsABe.

Comment: Rob, using `top: 50%;` doesn't vertically center an element. It positions the element **below** one-half of the browser's viewport height.

Comment: Did you take a look at the codepen? That's what transform: translateY(-50%); takes care of.