# Choppy animation on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to animate a block based on how far scrolled down the page I am, by using jQuery to change the CSS attribute.

when using a mouse wheel, there is a slight flicker of where it was and where it ends up being shown at the same time.

An example of this can be viewed at the following link.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/LPvES/10/show/light/

This behaviour is not smooth and feels 'choppy'.

I have no idea why this is happening. The expected behaviour should be this:

http://jsfiddle.net/LPvES/10/embedded/result/

I understand the irony of linking the exact same example. Only difference I can see between the two is that one is embedded in an iFrame, which is not a solution I want to use.

my JS code:

```
var icons = {
    header: "iconClosed",
    activeHeader: "iconOpen"
};

$('.main--content').accordion({
    header: ".accordion header",
    heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible: true,
    icons: icons
});

function accordionIcon() {

    var icon = $('.ui-accordion-header-icon.iconOpen');
    var iconClosed = $('.ui-accordion-header-icon.iconClosed');

    if (icon[0]) {
        var article = $('.ui-accordion-header-icon.iconOpen').closest('.article')

        if (article.offset().top - window.scrollY > 200) {

            if (icon.css('top') !== 0) {
                icon.css('top', 0)
            }

        } else if (article.offset().top - window.scrollY < 200) {
            // article.outerHeight() - (icon.offset().top - article.offset().top) > 0
            if (article.offset().top - (window.scrollY + 200) < article.outerHeight() && window.scrollY + $(window).height() - article.offset().top < article.outerHeight()) {

                var position = (window.scrollY + 200) - article.offset().top

                // if(icon.css('transform') === none){
                icon.css('top', position)
                // }

                if (icon.hasClass('iconExtend')) {
                    icon.removeClass('iconExtend')
                }

            } else if (window.scrollY + $(window).height() - article.offset().top > article.outerHeight()) {

                if (icon.css('top') !== article.outerHeight() + 30) {
                    icon.css('top', article.outerHeight() + 30)
                }

                if (!icon.hasClass('iconExtend')) {
                    icon.addClass('iconExtend')
                }

            } else {

                if (icon.css('top') !== article.outerHeight()) {
                    icon.css('top', article.outerHeight())
                }

                if (!icon.hasClass('iconExtend')) {
                    icon.addClass('iconExtend')
                }

            }
        }
    }

    if (iconClosed[0]) {

        if (iconClosed.css('top') !== 0) {
            iconClosed.css('top', 0)
        }

        if (iconClosed.hasClass('iconExtend')) {
            iconClosed.removeClass('iconExtend')
        }

    }
}

function raf() {

    window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
    })();

    requestAnimFrame(raf);

    accordionIcon();
}

raf();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tried utilizing `css` `position:fixed` on `block` until reach requirement `height` of `$(document).height()` at `scroll` `event`, then call single `css` `transition` (change to `position:absolute`) ?

Comment: I tried going down the `position: fixed` path, but that's relative to the window and the maths for that for what i'm doing is completely over my head.

Comment: Try this (potentially adjustable) pattern http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746887/detect-when-user-scrolled-down-and-reached-center-of-page/

Comment: Don't use `top` instead use `transform:translate3d(0,0,0)` when attempting to animate elements. It hardware accelerates the animation making it smoother. So for example top: 0 is essentially the same as transform:translate3d(0,0,0), and top:10px would be the same as transform:translate3d(0,10px,0);

Comment: Unfortunately I've pinpointed the issue. It has to do with the way browsers reflow, and the way chrome scrolls (this issue is chrome specific). Since chrome doesn't have a soft scroll enabled by default, when you scroll using your mousewheel it 'steps' down the page in alotments of 100px. Since the jump between two reflows is relatively large (as opposed to using the scroll bar), it appears as if the block is in two places at once. There doesn't really seem to be a way around it short of using `position: fixed` which has its own issues.

Comment: @user3277810 you're a genius! Setting `position:fixed` solved my problem. Could you answer your own question with this information? I'm sure it will help a lot of other people out there.